# postgreSQL get index of a row that is outside the limit you searched for

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL and I am not sure how to properly search my question so I will ask here.

[Please see this link to see the SQL tables and queries I am working with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1d550/1)

In this example there are 6 rows and I am limiting my search to start at the first index and give me at most 2.  However, I would like to know the index of the row that has id 1.

When I use the query I describe in sqlfiddle, It shows me rows with id 5 and 23.  But it doesn't include the row with id 1.  However, I need to know the index of the row with id 1..

[click here to see the full list](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1d550/2)

The link above prints out all of the rows and we can see that index 3 has the row containing id 1.

---

However I need to know that index without asking for the entire Array.

Why is this important?  Well, lets say that we have 1 million rows.  And if I ask for a million rows, that would mean allocating an array of one million.  I could parse the array until I find the id I am looking for.  However, allocating a million is way too costly.

Lets say for example that the row I am looking for resides in index 26, But I make my query so that it starts at index 0 and limits to 10.  The array that I get from this query would not contain index 26.  However I still need to know that it IS at index 26.

So this magic query would give me two things:

1. the top ten rows of the sorted rows
2. the index of a specified id (e.g. id of 1) regardless of its placement in the list.

---

Is this a possible query?

---

Clarification:
I use the word index to mean the row number.
If a we query a list of names from the db, we could get something like this:

```
bob
frank
dawn
```

then bob would be at index 0, frank would be at index 1 and dawn at index 2.

If I ORDER BY name ASC then the list of names would become

```
bob
dawn
frank
```

bob would be index 0 dawn would be index 1 and frank would be index 2.

I hope this makes things more clear.

Comment: What do you mean "the index"?  You have no columns with that name.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I made a clarification at the bottom of my question.  Please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the row number, use the `row_number()` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ud.id, ud.team_name, ui.name, ui.date_created,
             row_number() over (order by ui.name, ui.id) as rownumber
      FROM user_data ud JOIN
           user_infos ui
           ON ui.id = ud.id  
      WHERE ui.date_created BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '1 year' AND NOW()  
     ) t
WHERE rownumber <= 10 or id = 1;
```

If you want them in order, just add `order by rownumber` as the last statement.